# How to map both keymaps `<C-w>q` and `<C-w><C-q>` to do nothing?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, vim-windows

As title. I usually mistyped `<C-w>` into `<C-w><C-q>` and it close the window I was working on. That is really annoying... I have tried mapping this keymap into `<nop>` but it didn't work as expected:

- When I typed `<C-w><C-q>` very fast, then indeed nothing happened, as expected.
- But when I typed `<C-w>` and delayed the `<C-q>`, it still closed the window I was on.

Does anyone know what happened in my case? The same argument holds for `<C-w>q` too.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I see that If I wait after hitting <C-w> the key indicator change from `ü^DW` to `^W` and the mapping fail to catch the code `^W^Q`.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt: Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Remark: On Neovim I get `<80>ü^DW` instead of `ü^DW` (gVim)

Comment: Does it has something to do with `:h 'timeoutlen`?

Comment: @gildux: but `<C-q>` itself should not close the window. In fact `<C-q>` is default to enter `V-Block` mode.

Comment: Interesting, and good point. I've never use that …and mapped `<C-q>` to `:qa!` at work. You've catch a serious thing…